# PDF to ByteArray Conversion

Tags: java, pdf

We have written a java code where we are trying to convert PDF to Bytearray.

But the problem is when we try to convert and try to print the converted output we get only 8 to 10 characters only .why is it so ? when i covert the whole pdf it has to be a large no of characters .

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test\\P12.pdf"));
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test\\pdfoutput.xml"));

                         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                bs.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            System.out.println(in);
            byte[] bytes = bs.toByteArray();

                System.out.println(bs.toString());
        out.write(bytes);

}
```

Comment: There is no conversion here. You've read the PDF file into a byte array. It is still in PDF format. Not printable with `println().`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to extract all text data from the PDF?

Comment: No i dont want to read all text data..just simple PDF-->ByteArray format thats't it. Can you please let me know where do i need to change the code

Comment: On a sidenote: If you don't want to scare people with weird symbols in your output, you might want to consider encoding the byte array in Base64.

Comment: Change the code to do what? It copies the data to the byte array correctly, and to the output file (although as PDF, not as XML): it just doesn't print it correctly, but it can't do that without conversion to text. You seem to be expecting something magical to happen with ordinary streams code. It won't.

Comment: No but if i am coverting the complete pdf to bytearray then why do i get only around 8 to 10 characters ,....actually it has to be large no of characters if i am not wrong ?

Comment: You aren't converting anything. I've already told you that. You are *reading* a *file* into a *byte array.* This is a bitwise copy operation. Not a conversion. When you print it, you get whatever the undefined result of printing PDF (binary) data directly to the console is. It's not a valid operation. Solution: don't do it. If you want to view the PDF, use a PDF reader. If you want to convert it, convert it with iText or some other library. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is binary data. So a `toString` will probably just output the so called PDF signature, PDF + version + some intentionally non-ASCII chars.

As XML is even less likely.

There exists for instance the itext library for reading a PDF.

BTW `in.close()` would be a good idea too.

Comment: And `out.close(),` and not trying to print an input stream.

Answer (score 0):

> We have written a java code where we are trying to convert PDF to Bytearray.

No you haven't. You have written code that *reads* a *file*, without conversion, *into* a byte array. This is a bitwise copy operation, not a conversion.

> But the problem is when we try to convert

There is no conversion here, other than the almost certainly invalid conversion of the ByteArrayOutputStream to a String.

> and try to print the converted output we get only 8 to 10 characters only

You get junk. Binary junk. You get the original, unconverted, PDF, with all its binary characters, probably including lots of CR and BS characters. It isn't a valid operation. Solution: don't do it.

> why is it so?

Because you haven't converted anything.

> when i covert the whole pdf it has to be a large no of characters

No doubt, but you haven't converted anything yet. If you want see the text, use a PDF viewer, or write some code that uses a library like iText.

You have not yet begun to fight.